# WebApi OData batch request starts and end on different threads. How avoid?

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, asp.net-web-api, odata

Imagine, you have created your special message handler as:

```
public class OutputingHandler: MessageProcessingHandler
{
    protected override HttpRequestMessage ProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Output.Write("ENTER: request: {0}, thread: {1}", request.RequestUri, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return request;
    }

    protected override HttpResponseMessage ProcessResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Output.Write("EXIT:  request: {0}, thread: {1}", response.RequestMessage.RequestUri,
                     Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then you register this handler in GlobalConfiguration in Global.asax

Then you create batching request from Client, which inserts 2 instances into your DataService.

In my case output looks like

```
ENTER: request: http://localhost:61562/odata/$batch, thread: 20
ENTER: request: http://localhost:61562/odata/Persons, thread: 7
Create entity1, thread 7
EXIT:  request: http://localhost:61562/odata/Persons, thread: 7
ENTER: request: http://localhost:61562/odata/Persons, thread: 7
Create entity2, thread 7
EXIT:  request: http://localhost:61562/odata/Persons, thread: 7
EXIT:  request: http://localhost:61562/odata/$batch, thread: 7
```

As you see, batch request starts on thread #20 and ends on thread #7. I think its very strange behaviour. Anybody knows workaround?

Let me explain, why i want start and finish batch request on same thread: 
When batch request starts, I open transaction and when it ends, I close transaction. I use distributed transactions from System.Transactions namespace, they require same thread on Open/Close actions.

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

It sounds like you're trying to use DataSlots to store your transaction on the initiating thread.  Using a web platform, this is easy to get around using Aspect Oriented Programming.  I use the [Unity](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/) nuget package with the [Unity Interception Extensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Interception/) to control my entity framework context and transaction scope.  Then tie it all together with [Unity boostrapper for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/).

I would highly suggest using Interception with Unity.  And since you're using HTTP, you can use PerRequestLifetimeManager as the life time manager to ensure each request will have the original injected objects you started with.

Here's a complete MSDN write up for [Interception using Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx).

Here's a code sample I threw together as a quick example...

```
public class EntityFrameworkConnectionCallHandler : ICallHandler
{
       public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
      IMethodReturn returnValue;

      using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
      {
        // allow message sink to proceed...
        returnValue = getNext()(input, getNext);

        returnValue.InvokeAfterCall(
          input,
          @return =>
          {
            if (returnValue.Exception == null)
            {
              transactionScope.Complete();
            }
          });
      }

      return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Here's a couple of extension methods I use to make registering for the interception a lot easier.

```
public static class UnityWebExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the interception policies used for pre and post processing AOP.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The container.</param>
    /// <param name="namespacePrefix">The namespace prefix.  NYSEFC is default</param>
    /// <returns>The DI container for fluent API method chaining</returns>
    public static IUnityContainer RegisterInterceptionPolicies(this IUnityContainer container, string namespacePrefix = "MyBaseNamespace-ReplaceMe")
    {
      container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

      var first = new InjectionProperty("Order", 1);

      container.Configure<Interception>()
        .AddPolicy("EntityFrameworkConnectionPolicy")
        .AddMatchingRule<NamespaceMatchingRule>(
          new InjectionConstructor(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.*", namespacePrefix), true))
        .AddCallHandler<EntityFrameworkConnectionCallHandler>(first);

      // Enable the PerRequestLifetimeManager automatic disposal module.
      // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx
      DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));

      container.RegisterType<IDatabaseSettings, DatabaseSettings>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

      return container;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the layers of the distributed architecture types creating an AOP interception
    /// point prior to the <typeparamref name="TBusinessLayer" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TIBusinessLayer">The interface type of the business layer.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TBusinessLayer">The type of the business layer.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TIRepository">The interface type of the repository.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TRepository">The type of the repository.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TIContext">The interface type of the context.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TContext">The type of the context.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="container">The Microsoft Unity container.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The DI container for fluent API method chaining
    /// </returns>
    public static IUnityContainer RegisterDistributedLayers<TIBusinessLayer, TBusinessLayer, TIRepository, TRepository, TIContext, TContext>(
      this IUnityContainer container)
      where TBusinessLayer : TIBusinessLayer
      where TRepository : TIRepository
      where TContext : TIContext, IContext
    {
      container
        .RegisterType<TIBusinessLayer, TBusinessLayer>(
          new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(),
          new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>())
        .RegisterType<TIRepository, TRepository>()
        .RegisterType<TIContext, TContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

      return container;
    }
}
```

You can use the extension methods like:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container
  .RegisterInterceptionPolicies()
  .RegisterDistributedLayers<
    IMyBusinessLayer, MyBusinessLayer,
    IMyRepositoryLayer, MyRepositoryLayer,
    IMyContext, MyContext>();
```

After you've figured all that out, the only thing left is to use [Unity's dependency injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) which ties into MVC & Web Api very nicely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Werewolf, thanks for detailed response! But in my case your solution not suitable, because my company doesn't use EF (we have Oracle via NHibernate), and company don't want to use unity dependency (other containers). And the main problem is still: different Enter\Exit threads when processing batch request

Comment: Understandable...  My example using EF can be switch to any transaction based system.  It's the concept of AOP I was trying to convey, really.  I know AOP is a rabbit hole that misses Wonderland and ends up on the other side of the world, yet it's a VERY powerful tool when used for items such as logging, global exception monitoring, database interaction and anything else that's cookie cutter code used in every method over and over again. Another way of putting it... Keeping your code base DRY.  Hope you're able to find your solution.